# C# List Value Error

Tags: c#

When I try to access items from a list in another class, I get the error:

**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

Do I need a set accessor too, in another (or the same) list, or is there a problem with my code?

**WordList.cs**
*Updated*

```
    private List<string> words = new List<string>();
    private List<string> anagrams = new List<string>();

    public void addword(string word)
    {
        Words.Add(word);
        Anagrams.Add(anagram(word)); //Note: 'anagram' is a  (public) String which makes an anagram of the word, and returns it
    }
    public List<string> Words
    {
        get
        { return words; }
    }
    public List<string> Anagrams
    {
        get
        { return anagrams; }
    }
```

**game.cs**
*Updated*

```
    public void newword()
    {
        WordList list = new WordList();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(0, WordList.Anagrams.Count);
        info.Text = "The anagram is " + list.Anagrams[num] + " guess the original word";
    }
```

**Note: I still get the same error**

Comment: if `Wordlist.info.count == list.Anagrams.Count` that should work fine. why arent you using `list.Anagrams.Count` for your `rnd.Next()` call? Also you are creating the `new Wordlist()` isnt it empty at that point?

Comment: Why is `info.count` static? And i see no code updating it.

Comment: Your edited version won't even compile. Instead of Wordlist.Anagrams, list.Anagrams...

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete and unreliable. And any way the best solution is that you (learn to) use the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is at line - `list.Anagrams[num]`.

`num` is out of range since `list.info.Count` might be greater than `list.Anagrams.Count` which resulting in generating number greater than the anagrams list count.

Instead of

```
int num = rnd.Next(0, WordList.info.count);
```

it should be -

```
int num = rnd.Next(0, list.Anagrams.count);
```

---

Moreover in your method you are initializing a new list

```
 WordList list = new WordList();
```

but you haven't add anything to its `Anagrams` list, hence it's `count is 0`.
So indexer won't work for this list unless you add items to this list.

This should work -

```
public void newword()
{
    WordList list = new WordList();
    list.Anagrams.Add("Test1");  <-- Add items to list before accessing it
    list.Anagrams.Add("Test2");
    list.Anagrams.Add("Test3");
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int num = rnd.Next(0, list.Anagrams.Count);
    info.Text = "The anagram is " + list.Anagrams[num] +
                 " guess the original word";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use

```
   int num = rnd.Next(0, list.Anagrams.Count - 1)
```

since the count of a list is always bigger than the last index.
EDIT: The second parameter for Random.Next is inclusive upper bound not exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Just try it on a single form - that should work - I think :)

Comment: Would you mind explaining that how single form will fix this error?

Comment: @RohitVats - I tried something like that before and it didn't work when passing values, but it did on the same form